# VS Code's Source Control doesn't add or track newly added files

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Using Visual Studio Code's latest version and GitLens, I also use Remote SSH extensions from Microsoft

This happened after "moving" a folder.

When adding a new file or folder in the current git repository.
Git and Source Control don't track it.

My .gitignore content:

```
*
!/resources/
!/server.cfg
!/server2.cfg
!/run.sh
```

I tried adding a folder on /resources/folder or /resources/folder/folder

The file explorer on VS Code shows a grayed-out folder/file when creating a new one or moving a new one.

If I do change a file that is not grayed out, Source Control/Git can track the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! instead of adding * in the gitignore file you need to add /*